# Will sending an HTTP Header with Accept: text/html only download text from the page?

Tags: http, http-headers

I'm writing a simple crawler, and ideally to save bandwidth, I'd only like to download the text and links on the page. Can I do that using HTTP Headers? I'm confused about how they work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track to solving the problem.

I'm not sure how much you already know about HTTP headers, but basically an HTTP header is just a string formatting for a web server - it follows a protocol - and is pretty straightforward in that aspect.  **You write a request, and receive a response.**  The requests look like the things you see in the Firefox plugin LiveHTTPHeaders at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829/.

I wrote a small post at my site http://blog.gnucom.cc/2010/write-http-request-to-web-server-with-php/ that shows you how you can write a request to a web server and then later read the response.  If you only accept text/html you'll only accept a subset of what is available on the web (so yes, it will "optimize" your script to an extent).  Note this example is really low level, and if you're going to write a spider you may want to use an existing library like cURL or whatever other tools your implementation language offers.

Comment: Yes, I'm using multi-curl to fetch pages, so are you sure that sending text/html will ignore all media types?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, with using `Accept: text/html` you should only get HTML as a valid responses. That’s at least how it ought to be.

But in practice there is a huge difference between the standards and the actual implementations. And proper [content negotiation](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec12.html#sec12) (that’s what `Accept` is for) is one of the things that are barely supported.

Answer (score 3):

An HTML page contains just the text plus some tag markup.

Images, scripts and stylesheets are (usually) external files that are referenced from the HTML markup. This means that if you request a page, you will already receive just the text (without the images and other stuff).

Since you are writing the crawler, you should make sure it doesn't follow URLs from images, scripts or stylesheets.

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe that `GET /foobar.png` will return the image even if you send `Accept: text/html`. For this reason I believe you should just filter what kind of URLs you crawl.

In addition, you may try to read the response headers in the crawler and close the connection before you read the body if the `Content-Type` is not `text/html`. It might be worthwhile for undesired larger files.

Comment: Yes, sending `Accept: text/html` to the server still returns images from Apache